# TeamCity with TFS - workspace problems

Tags: tfs, teamcity, workspace, teamcity-5.0

We have been using CC.NET as our CI server for a month or so now, which has worked ok with TFS. In the config we were able to specify the TFS server, username, password, project and workspace which is all good.

Now we are moving over to TeamCity mainly because it just seams more solid and is much nicer to use. The problem is getting it work with TFS.

For the purpose of this, both the workspace and machine name are "BuildMachine", username is "BuildUser" TFS project is "$/Project/Dev/Website"

I seam to have set it up correctly, I think, as when testing the connection it is successful. When I run a build I get a TFS error: "RunBuildException when running build stage UpdateSourcesFromServer."

It goes on to say: "No matched workspaces were found. Will recreate workspace and perofming clean checkout."

It then tries to create a new workspace something like this: TeamCity-S-sqa9qe2aulx22gz4rzkogl5kr/BuildUser

It tries to set up some mappings and then fails because: "The working folder C:\ is already in use by the workspace BuildMachine;BuildUser on computer BuildMachine".

This seams ok as this is the workspace that CC.net was using, and c:\project\dev\website is the path to the project. The problem is, why didn't TeamCity pick this up and use this workspace? Why does it try to create its own new one? Any idea how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: what is the path to "Checkout directory" under "Version control settings" in your build configuration?

Comment: I have tried leaving it blank, setting it to just c:\ and also setting it to c:\project\dev\website. All result in the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed this by simply changing the path for the BuildMachine workspace to `c:\BuildMachineWorkspace\` instead of just `c:\`.

I guess this means that the whole of `c:\` is no longer a workspace therefore other workspaces can be created on `c:\`.